# Wcf inhereted models

Tags: wcf

```
[DataContract]
Base
{ 
     [DataMember]
     public int Id {get;set;}
}

[DataContract]
A : Base 
{
     [DataMember]
     public string Value {get;set;}
}

[ServiceContract]
interface IService
{
    [OperationContract]
    void SetValue (Base base);
}
```

is there a way to use the service like the following style:

```
new Service ().SetValue (new A ());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As well as changing the way you're calling the service as indicated by @Flo, you'll also need to make a small change to prepare the Data Contract Serializer to deal with the inheritance hierarchy.

The easiest way of doing this is decorating Base with the [KnownTypeAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.knowntypeattribute.aspx). Like this,

```
[DataContract]
[KnownType(typeof(A))]
Base
{ 
     [DataMember]
     public int Id {get;set;}
}

[DataContract]
A : Base 
{
     [DataMember]
     public string Value {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: Yes but by this knowntype way; for all the new class i added i also add a knowntype in base too.

Comment: That's true - but have a look at Davy Brion's Known Type Provider: http://davybrion.com/blog/2008/07/the-known-type-provider/

Answer (score 1):

You tagged this WCF so I assume you want to use it.

You need to connect to the endpoint using the ChannelFactory and then open the channel.

This will not work:

```
new Service ().SetValue (new A ());
```

---

You need to do smth. like this:

```
using (var scf = new ChannelFactory< IService >(<Binding>,<EndpointAddress>)
 {
   IService proxy = scf.CreateChannel();
   proxy.SetValue(new (A));
 }
```

This will return you a proxy object that implements the IService interface. You can call the SetValue on this object.